# How do I check the continuity and differentiability of this function?

Tags: continuity

The function is
$f(x)= \frac{tan(\pi[x-\pi])}{1+[x]^2}$, 
where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. 
I have four options. One or more are correct. 
They are - 1) $f(x)$ is discontinuous at some $x$,
2)$f’(x)$ exists for all $x$,
3)$f’(x)$ exists for all $x$ but $f’’(x)$ doesn’t exist,
4)$f(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ but $f’(x)$ doesn’t exist for some $x$

Comment: Hint: You have $\tan(k\pi)$ for some integer $k$ in the numerator.

Comment: Okay,so the numerator will always approach 0,and hence the function is continuous at all points,since it will always take the value 0. Am I correct? What about differentiability?

Comment: It doesn't just approach $0$. It *is* $0$ for all $x$. What's the derivative of a constant?

Comment: ....Oh. I’m sorry,yeah,the greatest integer function ensures that it is equal to 0. Okay,so it’s differentiable as well and the derivative is 0 at all points?

Comment: Sounds like you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!